# Discount Code applies to cart successfully but doesn't do anything. Am I missing something?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, debugging, discounts

Standard 10 dollars off discount setup.  Although it says it is applied, it doesn't give me any kind of a discount.  None of the discounts work, I've made multiple and tried different options but it still doesn't work.  Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share the discount setup you have used.

Comment: @LukeHolder I've added screenshots of the discount.

Comment: Is your item on sale?

Comment: No I have no Sale set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the discount not being applied is that nearly all your products have not been marked as promotable (by looking at your database):

Screenshot: http://jmp.sh/3FAK6NH

No sales or discounts can be applied to a non-promotable product.